# How would I write a for loop to increment a string by 1?

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I'm developing one of my first apps in Android Studio. I'm trying to figure out how to write more efficient code.

This is what I have so far:

```
` ArrayList<String> numbersList = new ArrayList<>();
            numbersList.add("1");
            numbersList.add("2");
            numbersList.add("3");
            numbersList.add("4");
            numbersList.add("5");
            numbersList.add("6");
            numbersList.add("7");
            numbersList.add("8");
            numbersList.add("9");
            numbersList.add("10");`
```

I would like to go all the way up to 100, but I know manually typing  each one is not the recommended or efficient way of writing code. So, what could I do?

Comment: for(int i=1;i<100;i++){numbersList.add(i+"");}

Comment: Why store numbers in a `List<String>`? Why not just deal with numbers until you need to output them as a String and then convert them with `Integer.toString(numberValue)` instead?

Answer (score 6):

Just use an integer loop and parse each one as a string before you add to your list:

```
ArrayList<String> numbersList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
    numbersList.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8

```
List<String> list = IntStream.range(1, 100).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop. There are several resources online to learn more about this.

```
ArrayList<String> numbersList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
  numbersList.add(Integer.toString(i));
}
```